# SSIS package works in Visual Studio, fails under SQL Agent - Where do I look?

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata

I have an SSIS package using an oData source to pull a SharePoint library into SQL Server.

Under Visual Studio, the package runs fine, and pulls the data from the production SharePoint site into SQL Server no problem.

As part of a SQL Agent job, it fails, with a VS_ISBROKEN error, and error codes of 0xC004706B and 0xC0024107.  The remote server returned a 404 error (not found), and said that the job failed validation and returned a status VS_ISBROKEN.

I've done internet searching all day every day until my eyes cross, and have no idea what's going on.  I don't want to be spoon-fed, but I would like help in knowing where to look so I can have a chance to find the answer.

Comment: If it is not finding the server there may be firewalls on the server of the agent job runs on stopping it from seeing the server you are looking for?  Or it could not be on the same network (or something similar).  Or it could be (but less likely due to the error) the User running the agent job does not have permissions on the server you are trying to hit

Comment: That last point of yours is what I want to investigate, but everything else isn't a factor.  Other related jobs on the same server run just fine, pulling from the same SharePoint site on the same network.

The SharePoint Architect isn't in yet (it's 1000 east coast time, and we're in the Northern Virginia area, about an hour south of DC)....otherwise I'd have him look at the logs for the 45 minutes yesterday where I was doing testing.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution has been found.

First, some background.  I have control of the development environment.  I do not have control of production.  The production DBA was running the SSIS package from Visual Studio, and it was working.  As part of a SQL Agent job, it was not.

the problem was that their SQLAgent userid had permissions on our SharePoint site, and *our* special userid did not, even though we got it for situations like this.

The SharePoint architect removed the wrong userid's permissions, restored the right userid's permissions, and the job was rerun, and it worked like a charm.

thanks everyone.